# What is the role of " isViewFromObject (View view, Object object)" in FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with my View Pager. The Fragment returned is not displayed on the screen if `isViewFromObject (View view, Object object)` returns `false`. Why is that? 
The developer doc says `Determines whether a page View is associated with a specific key object as returned by instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int). This method is required for a PagerAdapter to function properly.` But I am not clear with this definition.

Answer (score 25):

The method    `instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)` returns `Object` for a particular view. `PagerAdapter` implementation is considering this `Object` as a `key` value when viewpager changes a page.

So, if we return the view itself from `instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)`, then our `key` for that page becomes the view itself. We can check `return view == object;` from `isViewFromObject (View view, Object object)` which will always return `true` and our pages will display :

```
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
```

Some more insights from post https://stackoverflow.com/a/16772250/1994950 :

When you slide, the `ViewPager` gets view position from an array or instantiates it and compare this view with children of `ViewPager` with adapters method `public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)`. The view which equals to object is displayed to the user on `ViewPager`. If there is no view then the blank screen is displayed.

Here is `ViewPager` method where the view is compared to object:

```
ItemInfo infoForChild(View child) {
    for (int i=0; i<mItems.size(); i++) {
        ItemInfo ii = mItems.get(i);
        if (mAdapter.isViewFromObject(child, ii.object)) {
            return ii;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```