# ViewPager layouts are not displayed

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to use viewpager without fragments, only with layout files, but the layout is not displayed only tabdots, what am I doing wrong?

activity_ponto_biometria.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/photos_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/photos_viewpager"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AdapterAjudaMarcacao.java

```
public class AdapterAjudaMarcacao extends PagerAdapter {


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
                        Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    int layout;
    if (position == 0){
        layout = R.layout.pop_up_ajuda_1;
    } else if (position == 1){
        layout = R.layout.pop_up_ajuda_2;
    } else {
        layout = R.layout.pop_up_ajuda_3;
    }
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
            .inflate(layout, container, false);
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return false;
}
}
```

PontoBiometriaActivity.java

```
public class PontoBiometriaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ponto_biometria);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

    setTitle("Ponto Coletivo");

    ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.photos_viewpager);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new AdapterAjudaMarcacao();
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager, true);

}
```

[image: see blank viewpager]
the amount of tabdots is displayed, but the content is not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `isViewFromObject()` method should `return view == object;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69290317/viewpager-layouts-are-not-displayed#comment122469417_69290317) is right.
Instead of:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return false;
}
```

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/PagerAdapter#isViewFromObject(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object)), this method is required for a PagerAdapter to function properly.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32709553/13349907) explains:

> The method `instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)` returns `Object` for a particular view. `PagerAdapter` implementation is considering this `Object` as a `key` value when viewpager changes a page.

> So, if we return the view itself from `instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)`, then our `key` for that page becomes the view itself. We can check `return view == object`; from `isViewFromObject (View view, Object object)` which will always return `true` and our pages will display.

Comment: it worked, thank you very much, I didn't pay attention to this detail