# app with viewpager and picasso keeps stoping

Tags: java, android

I am doing image carousel from urls with tutorial. When I open the app it says 'app keeps stoping'. Using `picasso`, dependency was added. Permission to internet enabled in `AndroidMainfest`. In android studio there are no errors.

activity_main

```
<android.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
     ...
     android:id="@+id/view_pager"
</android.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] imageUrls;

    ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
            ...
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have layout xml for carousel items? If yes, ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277892/instantiateitemviewgroup-int-in-pageradapter-and-addview-in-viewpager-confusi

Comment: There must be a stack trace related to error. Please [edit] the question and post it here. Otherwise it's difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: no, i take images from urls

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, I had to put ViewPager inside ConstraintLayout